# Python: "return <tuple>" keeps returning None

Tags: python, function, recursion, return, tuples

I have the following code:

```
def subStringMatchExact(target,key,matches=(),base=0):
    if find(target,key) != -1:
        matches += (find(target,key)+base,)
        base += find(target,key)+len(key)
        subStringMatchExact(target[find(target,key)+len(key):],key,matches,base)
    else:
        print matches
        return matches
```

When I run the function, say for instance `subStringMatchExact('abcdabcdababcdedakcdobcdabcd','abc')`, the `print matches` line will have my interpreter print `(0,4,10,24)`, which is correct. However the line `return matches` returns value `None`.

Similarly when I call `print subStringMatchExact('abcdabcdababcdedakcdobcdabcd','abc')`, the interpreter also gives `None`.

Can anyone help me correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rather think that you intended to return the recursive value on line 5. As it is, it just calls it and then continues to the end of the method, returning `None`. So, all you need is the insertion of the `return` keyword.

```
def subStringMatchExact(target,key,matches=(),base=0):
    if find(target,key) != -1:
        matches += (find(target,key)+base,)
        base += find(target,key)+len(key)
        return subStringMatchExact(target[find(target,key)+len(key):],key,matches,base)
    else:
        print matches
        return matches
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean for the statement at the end of the `if` clause to say:

```
return subStringMatchExact(...)
```

The `return` statement beneath your `print` statement is indeed working — it is successfully sending the answer back up the chain to the instance of the function that called it — but then the copy of the calling function is throwing it away. Without a `return` in the first clause of the `if` statement, a `None` gets returned instead.